# How do I Lock camera rotation of FPS controller from standard asset when trigger enter in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am beginner of game development I want to make when Player is enter the trigger the game is over so player's movement and camera rotation is stop. This is my code I can make player's movement is stop but camera rotate is not stop I can still rotate so help me!

```
public GameObject canvas;
public Transform Camera;

void Start()
{
    canvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);    
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    Camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to add a bool variable in your Camera script and change it when the player enters and exit the trigger like so :

```
public bool isLocked;

 void DoRotate() {
     if(!islocked)
         // do stuff
}
```

Another possibility would be to manually overwrite the camera rotation as long as the player is in the trigger zone which is not the ideal solution. In this case, you need to use the function OnTriggerStay instead of OnTriggerEnter.

For example :

```
public GameObject canvas;
public Transform Camera;

void Start()
{
    canvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);    
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider col) 
{ 
      Camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
}
```